# Laravel homestead/nginx error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I've been using the vagrant box Laravel Homestead and it's all working fine with PHP projects. But now I have a AngularJS project which only has html.

When I map my project in the `Homestead.yaml` file I get a `No input file specified.` error.

Did anyone had this error as well? Or has someone a solution for this?

My config is:

```
folders:
- map: D:/Laravel-Projects/front-end
  to: /home/vagrant/Laravel-Projects/front-end

sites:
- map: angular.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Laravel-Projects/front-end
```

Comment: Did you reload Vagrant? E.g. ``vagrant provision`` or ``vagrant reload --provision``

Comment: That's all I've got, sorry. :( Hope you manage to solve it.

Comment: Well I tried it again and it's working now, lol... @JoelHinz

Comment: Oh, haha, that's great :)

Comment: Well, the index.html is getting loaded, but my included files can't be loaded.. `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 0):

you should be mapping the site to the public folder. Also, if all your projects are in the Laravel-Projects folder, just map it 1 level up:

```
folders:
    - map: D:/Laravel-Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel-Projects

sites:
    - map: angular.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel-Projects/front-end/public
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `vagrant up --provision` in your homestead folder after routing the site's entry folder to the root of your site.